# How can I fix marker and GMSCircle on the center in Google Maps ios?

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps

I want to fix the marker and the circle of it in the center of the map irrespective of the location coordinates using swift. If the user moves the camera on map I want it to keep showing up in the center without any flickering in radius or the marker and user should be able to increase and decrease the radius of the circle.
I used

```
circle.position = mapView.camera.target
```

but it didn't help.
So I wanna know how can I do that?
Please help.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your `ViewController` class needs to implement the `func mapView(mapView: GMSMapView!, didChangeCameraPosition position: GMSCameraPosition!)` method from `GMSMapViewDelegate`.

Inside the `func mapView(mapView: GMSMapView!, didChangeCameraPosition position: GMSCameraPosition!)` method, you can update the position of your circle. The method is *called repeatedly during any animations or gestures on the map (or once, if the camera is explicitly set).*

Sample code:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, GMSMapViewDelegate {

    var mapView: GMSMapView!
    var cirlce: GMSCircle!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let camera = GMSCameraPosition.cameraWithLatitude(-33.86,
            longitude: 151.20, zoom: 6)
        mapView = GMSMapView.mapWithFrame(CGRectZero, camera: camera)
        mapView.myLocationEnabled = true
        self.view = mapView

        mapView.delegate = self

        cirlce = GMSCircle(position: camera.target, radius: 100000)
        cirlce.fillColor = UIColor.redColor().colorWithAlphaComponent(0.5)
        cirlce.map = mapView
    }

    func mapView(mapView: GMSMapView!, didChangeCameraPosition position: GMSCameraPosition!) {
        print("\(position.target.latitude) \(position.target.longitude)")
        cirlce.position = position.target
    }

}
```

[image]

**Edited:**

If you want to make a circle irrelevant to your mapView camera movement, you can make a circular UIView on top of your mapView.

Sample code:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var mapView: GMSMapView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let camera = GMSCameraPosition.cameraWithLatitude(-33.86,
            longitude: 151.20, zoom: 6)
        mapView = GMSMapView.mapWithFrame(CGRectZero, camera: camera)
        mapView.myLocationEnabled = true
        self.view = mapView

        let circleView = UIView()
        circleView.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor().colorWithAlphaComponent(0.5)
        view.addSubview(circleView)
        view.bringSubviewToFront(circleView)
        circleView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        let heightConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: circleView, attribute: .Height, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: nil, attribute: .NotAnAttribute, multiplier: 1, constant: 100)
        let widthConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: circleView, attribute: .Width, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: nil, attribute: .NotAnAttribute, multiplier: 1, constant: 100)
        let centerXConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: circleView, attribute: .CenterX, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: view, attribute: .CenterX, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
        let centerYConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: circleView, attribute: .CenterY, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: view, attribute: .CenterY, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
        NSLayoutConstraint.activateConstraints([heightConstraint, widthConstraint, centerXConstraint, centerYConstraint])

        view.updateConstraints()
        UIView.animateWithDuration(1.0, animations: {
            self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
            circleView.layer.cornerRadius = CGRectGetWidth(circleView.frame)/2
            circleView.clipsToBounds = true
        })
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Well  I tried your code but the circle is moving jerkily as well along with the camera and that's not what I want to do. I want to make the circle static in the center and it shouldn't move. It should just stay in the center without showing any transition of movement no matter what. @ztan

Comment: @ztan how do I get the coordinates at the centre of the circle when the map is moved?

Comment: @Rao you can use `CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate = [mapView.projection coordinateForPoint:somePoint];`

Answer (score 2):

#### This is an updated version to Swift 3

```
import UIKit
import GoogleMaps

class ViewController: UIViewController, GMSMapViewDelegate {

var mapView: GMSMapView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    
    let camera = GMSCameraPosition.camera(withLatitude: -33.86,
                                          longitude: 151.20, zoom: 6)
    mapView = GMSMapView.map(withFrame: .zero, camera: camera)
    mapView.isMyLocationEnabled = true
    self.view = mapView
    
    mapView.delegate = self
    
    let circleView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 20, height: 10))
    circleView.backgroundColor = UIColor.red.withAlphaComponent(0.5)
    view.addSubview(circleView)
    view.bringSubview(toFront: circleView)
    
    circleView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    let heightConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: circleView, attribute: .height, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: nil, attribute: .notAnAttribute, multiplier: 1, constant: 100)
    let widthConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: circleView, attribute: .width, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: nil, attribute: .notAnAttribute, multiplier: 1, constant: 100)
    let centerXConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: circleView, attribute: .centerX, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: view, attribute: .centerX, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
    let centerYConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: circleView, attribute: .centerY, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: view, attribute: .centerY, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([heightConstraint, widthConstraint, centerXConstraint, centerYConstraint])
    
    view.updateConstraints()
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 1.0, animations: {
        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
        circleView.layer.cornerRadius = circleView.frame.width/2
        circleView.clipsToBounds = true
    })
    
}
func mapView(_ mapView: GMSMapView, didChange position: GMSCameraPosition) {
    print("\(position.target.latitude) \(position.target.longitude)")
     } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an update for SwiftUi

```
import GoogleMaps
import SwiftUI

/// The wrapper for `GMSMapView` so it can be used in SwiftUI
struct MapView: UIViewRepresentable {

//  @Binding var selectedMarker: GMSMarker?

  var onAnimationEnded: () -> ()

  private let gmsMapView = GMSMapView(frame: .zero)
  private let defaultZoomLevel: Float = 10
    
  func makeUIView(context: Context) -> GMSMapView {
    // Create a GMSMapView centered around the city of San Francisco, California
    let sanFrancisco = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 33.8465118, longitude: 35.5584162)
    gmsMapView.camera = GMSCameraPosition.camera(withTarget: sanFrancisco, zoom: defaultZoomLevel)
    gmsMapView.delegate = context.coordinator
    gmsMapView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    gmsMapView.isMyLocationEnabled = true
      
    return gmsMapView
  }

  func updateUIView(_ uiView: GMSMapView, context: Context) {
 
//    if let selectedMarker = selectedMarker {
//      let camera = GMSCameraPosition.camera(withTarget: selectedMarker.position, zoom: defaultZoomLevel)
//      print("Animating to position \(selectedMarker.position)")
//      CATransaction.begin()
//      CATransaction.setValue(NSNumber(floatLiteral: 5), forKey: kCATransactionAnimationDuration)
//      gmsMapView.animate(with: GMSCameraUpdate.setCamera(camera))
//      CATransaction.commit()
//    }
  }

  func makeCoordinator() -> MapViewCoordinator {
    return MapViewCoordinator(self)
  }
  

  final class MapViewCoordinator: NSObject, GMSMapViewDelegate {
      
    var mapView: MapView
    private var cirlce: GMSCircle!

    init(_ mapView: MapView) {
        self.mapView = mapView
        self.cirlce = GMSCircle(position: mapView.gmsMapView.camera.target, radius: 10000)
        self.cirlce.fillColor = UIColor(hexString: "#0076FF").withAlphaComponent(0.3)
        self.cirlce.strokeColor = UIColor(hexString: "#0076FF")
    }

    func mapView(_ mapView: GMSMapView, didTapAt coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D) {
//      let marker = GMSMarker(position: coordinate)
//      self.mapView.polygonPath.append(marker)
    }

    func mapView(_ mapView: GMSMapView, didChange position: GMSCameraPosition) {
               
     }
      
    func mapView(_ mapView: GMSMapView, idleAt position: GMSCameraPosition) {
      self.mapView.onAnimationEnded()
        
        DispatchQueue.main.async{
            self.cirlce.position = mapView.camera.target
            self.cirlce.map = mapView
        }
    }

  }
}
```